# How to setup Slack bot to ask users and then display their answers via command?

Tags: slack

I'd like to have command, let's say `/aboutme` which asks user few questions via PM and after that, if anyone uses for example `/about James`, then James responses to those questions are displayed.

Comment: Your question is technically way too broad for stackoverflow, but I decided to give you an answer anyways to help you get started on your Slack app. Please ask more specific question in the future. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

That is not hard to do:

- Create a [Slack app](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps), which reacts to [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands).
- on `/aboutme`store the answers in a database per user
- for asking the questions I would recommend to use [Dialogs](https://api.slack.com/dialogs), which work similar to HTML forms.
- on `/about @user`lookup the answers per user later when someone asked.

Note that your slack app will need to run on a web server and have its own database.

If you are new to Slack apps check out the excellent [documentation](https://api.slack.com/) and [tutorials](https://api.slack.com/tutorials) on the Slack page.